# "connection refused" on ssh reverse tunnel

Tags: ssh-tunnel

I have a single remote server with two (server) clients connecting using `autossh -nNT -R ...` Each client has a separate inbound port into the remote server. If I reboot the clients, I will get a `connection refused` message when attempting to reconnect from my local PC.

When I issue `netstat | grep ssh` on the remote server, I see multiple "ESTABLISHED" ssh connections. If I then issue a `sudo pkill --signal HUP sshd` on the server and then attempt to reach the clients that are configured to run autossh via the server (from my local PC), the connections succeed. I believe that when a client connection established through autossh is broken, it is unable to reestablish the connection. At first I thought it was the TCPKeepAlive/ClientAliveInterval  settings in sshd_config may've been affecting resources, so I commented them out and rebooted the server, but I am still observing the behavior.

`/var/log/messages` on the client seems to be filled with `ssh exited with error status 255; restarting ssh` while the `connection refused` condition exists.

What can I do to ensure that when a client connection is no longer active that the server frees resources in a timely manners so that the client can reestablish the connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried changing on the Server /etc/ssh/sshd_config these parameters?

- ClientAliveCountMax
- ClientAliveInterval

From http://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config

[image]

Comment: I had ClientAliveInterval set to 30 and ClientAliveCountMax set to 2 in sshd_config. That duration makes sense as if I sat there for a while sometimes it would appear to allow connection after some time. What I don't understand is the method by which autossh restores connections. I'm wondering if a ClientAliveInterval with a small value and a ClientAliveCountMax set to 1 would allow the behavior of autossh to properly recover the connection. I believe that I read somewhere that autossh by default uses the "ServerKeepAlive" functionality.